# Need help in visualising the lines with self implemented hough line detector in matlab

Tags: matlab, hough-transform, houghlines

I was able to recreate the hough() and houghpeaks() function in Matlab with the following codes, but I am currently struggling to dehough them from parameter space to image space.

```
%%% hough() function

corridor = imread('Corridor1.jpg');
grayCorridor = rgb2gray(corridor);
Canny_img = edge(grayCorridor, 'Canny');
[rows, cols] = size(Canny_img);
theta_maximum = 90;
rho_maximum = hypot(rows,cols) - 1;
theta_range = -theta_maximum:theta_maximum-1;
rho_range = -rho_maximum:rho_maximum;

Hough = zeros(length(rho_range), length(theta_range));
for j = 1:rows
    for i = 1:cols
        if Canny_img(j, i) ==1
            x = i - 1;
            y = j - 1;
            for T = theta_range
                R = round((x * cosd(T)) + (y * sind(T)));
                R_Index = R + rho_maximum + 1;
                T_Index = T + theta_maximum + 1;
                Hough(R_Index, T_Index) = Hough(R_Index, T_Index) + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end

%%% houghpeaks() function

[X,Y] = find(Hough>0.47*max(Hough(:)))

%Visualising them 

imshow(Hough,[],'XData',theta_range,'YData',rho_range,...
            'InitialMagnification','fit');
xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
axis on, axis normal, hold on;

pointsRho = rho_range(X(:));
pointsTheta = theta_range(Y(:));
plot(pointsTheta,pointsRho,'s','color','red');
```

[image: Hough space with peaks]
Here is my attempt at dehoughing them to image space. I first get the Rho and Theta pair into a list. I then created a set of binary matrices of the size imageRow x imageColumn x number of rhotheta pair.
Then I substitute all the x and y pixel coordinates into the function x*cos(theta) + y*sin(theta) = rho, and if left - right == 0, I would mark the location of the binary matrix(x,y) as 1 and I run this for all the theta pairs against all the x and y value and store them separately in the set of binary matrices mentioned above.

In the second for loop, I just went through all of the set of binary matrices I had obtained and just aggregate them into one binary matrix. My problem comes here, how do I combine the lines that I dehoughed into one line when they are close to each other? If I am able to do that, I might be able to visualize more houghpeaks by lowering the threshold I have set with [X,Y] = find(Hough>0.47*max(Hough(:))). Because right now if I were to lower the threshold by even 0.01, I would have many more lines that are so close to each other. And do you perhaps have a more elegant and better way of dehoughing?

```
for k = 1:length(pointsRho)
    for i = 1:1280 % Shoulda put 1:size(Canny_img,1) but putting number helps me visualise my logic 
                   % better while I am coding
        for j = 1:960
            r = pointsRho(k);
            t = pointsTheta(k);
            threshold = abs(i*cosd(t)+j*sind(t)-r);
            if threshold ==0
                allLines(j,i,k) = 1;
            end     
        end
    end
end

aggregatedImage = zeros(size(Canny_img));
for k = 1:length(pointsRho)
    for j = 1:1280
        for i = 1:960
            if allLines(i,j,k) ==1
                aggregatedImage(i,j) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end

figure,imshow(imfuse(aggregatedImage,corridor))
```

[image: Dehoughing the peaks into lines]

P/S: I thought that I could have possibly made the two loops into one for loop if I were to mark all of the pixel coordinates that fulfill x*cos(theta) + y*cos(theta) = r right away in only one binary matrix (as shown in the following code). However, I am not sure why when I did that the aggregatedImage is just all 0. Hence I decided to go with the above approach.

```
aggregatedImage = zeros(size(Canny_img));

for k = 1:length(pointsRho)
    for i = 1:1280
        for j = 1:960
            r = pointsRho(k);
            t = pointsTheta(k);
            threshold = abs(i*cosd(t)+j*sind(t)-r);
            if threshold ==0
                aggregatedImage(j,i) = 1;
            end     
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: That's not part of the HoughTransform, strictly. You want some algorithm that bunches together solutions that are close to one another.  In Houghspace you could look for each point whether other points are close and then take the center of gravity of those, weighted by the aggregate of each peak. Also if the customer is human, you could just make lines with low aggregates weaker.  Most uses of the HoughTransform are not trying to be so generic. Most of the time you know what you are looking for, a square or a circle of a certain size, so you just threshold it (or work with the illumination).

Comment: @roadrunner66 ahh so now I have the aggregated binary matrices, do I just check if the value at left,right, up, down has 1 and remove/keep them? Is there a good way of doing this? I am not sure how I can achieve that since the lines have different gradient etc.

Comment: In the Hough space the closeness means similar slope and similar distance to origin, i.e. similar line. One thing you could do is make a convolution of the Hough-space with a Gaussian (thereby averaging and making a single peak out of many close ones). Then after the convo look again for the max peaks. This way you incidentally increase the resolution, since now multiple close peaks contribute to your peak, your new peak has a non-integer resolution in Hough-space.